# Running android unit tests from the command line?

Tags: android, unit-testing, shell

I'm trying to run unit tests on the android platform in accordance with [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/testing_android.html). Say, for example, I want to run tests for Email application. I open `/apps/Email/tests/AndroidManifest.xml` file, look for the `<manifest>` element, and look at the `package` attribute, which is `com.android.email.tests`, and in the `<instrumentation>` element I look at the `android:name` attribute, which is `android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner`. Now I open the console, and run

```
$ . build/envsetup.sh
$ lunch 1
$ adb shell am instrument -w com.android.email.tests/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

But that fails:

```
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=ActivityManagerService
android.util.AndroidException: INSTRUMENTATION_FAILED: com.android.email.tests/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: Error=Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{com.android.email.tests/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}
```

So.. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please run 
python development/testrunner/runtest.py email

and then you will see it works :).

Basically you do not have com.android.email.tests package installed.

You can see what is available for instrumentation

```
pm list instrumentation
```

And you should see

> instrumentation:com.android.email.tests/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
>   (target=com.android.email)

And when doing

```
pm list packages
```

> package:com.android.email
>
> package:com.android.email.tests

Comment: Android doesn't use Python. Should be `adb shell pm list instrumentation`

Comment: Yes these are commands that you do in adb shell.

Python is not in android but used to be in framework for testing android http://androidxref.com/4.2_r1/xref/development/testrunner/runtest.py

Answer (score 3):

You may need to setup a test project with the `android create test-project` command first. Check this page on the Android Dev site: [Testing In Other IDE's](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/testing/testing_otheride.html) for more info. I've used this method to enable command line testing with ant.

Answer (score 2):

What I actually forgot to do was building and installing that test packages onto my device/emulator. Discovered that after doing:

```
$ adb shell
# cd data/packages
# ls
```

And no `com.android.email.tests` package there.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was this tag:

```
 <instrumentation
    android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    android:label="Tests for app.under.test.package"
    android:targetPackage="app.under.test.package" />
```

Firstly I had the `android:name` attribute wrong then the target package wrong (above is the correct solution)

Answer (score 1):

#### Test Package Not Installed on the Emulator

I had the exact same issue and realized that the test package hadn't been installed on the emulator, which is what @marekdef is saying.

Instead of using the command found in the generated test file, I used the following:

```
ant debug install test
```

*I had my test project in `<project_home>/tests` so the following command is what I ended up using from my **project home** directory:

```
(cd tests && ant debug install test;)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That worked for me, I was used for eclipse to create the test build, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I received the "Unable to find instrumentation info" error under this condition: I defined my test project with a src package name that was the same as that of the project-under-test. For example, the source for both projects was in package com.mycompany.android. This parallel-src-package setup worked fine in Eclipse, but on the emulator it very much appeared that the test apk was overwriting the app apk.

Fix: I changed the src packge of the test project to test.mycompany.android.

Note that, in either case, the Android manifest for the test project defines:

< manifest package="pkg-of-project-under-test" ...>

and

< instrumentation android:targetPackage="pkg-of-project-under-test" ...>

Comment: I just found that eclipse-Run does not care whether the manifest element defines package="pkg-of-project-under-test" (which is the value that eclipse inserts when it creates a new Android test project) or package="pkg-of-test-project". 

Why did I notice this? Well, eclipse-Build seems to care about that value. When I added the first Activity to my test project and edited the test manifest to describe it, eclipse started complaining that it couldn't find R when compiling my test activity. Changing the <manifest> package to pkg-of-test-project solved that problem.

Answer (score 0):

For gradle user you can use the following tasks:

```
$ gradle :project:installDebug :project:installDebugAndroidTest
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this `run_all_test.sh` script to run all unit and instrumented test:

```
#!/bin/bash
./gradlew --no-daemon clean test connectedCheck --stacktrace;
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "tests are successful"
else
    echo "tests FAILED"
    exit 1
fi
```

Explanation:

> - test -> execute all unit test
> - connectedCheck -> execute all instrumented test

You can start from here to customize it based on your needs following the documentation here: https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line

Answer (score 0):

[[Android test types]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59236788/4770877)

To run all tests from Command Line using gradlew[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49076817/4770877)

JUnit test (UnitTest suffix)

```
./gradlew test
./gradlew :<moduleName>:test<variantName>UnitTest
```

Instrument test(AndroidTest suffix)

```
./gradlew connectedAndroidTest
./gradlew :<moduleName>:connected<variantName>AndroidTest
```

If you want just to build tests and don't run them use `assemble`

```
//Unit
./gradlew :<moduleName>:assemble<variantName>UnitTest

//functional
./gradlew :<moduleName>:assemble<variantName>AndroidTest
```