# how do I add a package to androidtest?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

I created a sub-package under android test and when I try to run tests there I get this popup (ignore the red I changed it before posting):
[image]

I dont get this popup for tests in the root androidTest package, Im not sure whats happening. It looks like its going to add it to my gradle config for me if I run this? But I looked at my gradle files and don't see where this is referenced. I'd like to understand how this is working.

Comment: Gradle defaults to `src/androidTest/`. Did you make a package in there? Can you show it?

Comment: Alternatively, if it's just a regular Junit test, that goes in `src/test/java` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34397524/whats-the-difference-between-src-androidtest-and-src-test-folders

Comment: I made a new package under the default androidTest: AndroidStudioProjects/game/app/src/androidTest/java/com/mycomp/mygame/game01/Ship/ShipTest.java

Comment: Your image doesn't say game01

Comment: Yeah i edited it before posting. I just right clicked under the default androidTest package in intellij and created a new package and created the test in there

Comment: you should be able to right click any method and create a unit test for it

Comment: yeah I want to understand whats happening in the gradle config. How do I set this up manually and why isn't it working?

Comment: Gradle just defines where your tests are located based on the sourceSets. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#sourcesets