# Mockito verify only passes with AVD running

Tags: java, android, testing, mockito, mvp

I want to test a MVP-Pattern. So i have a Presenter class, which shall invoke the View methods when certain buttons are clicked. Now I want to verify, that the Presenter really invokes the Method, so I wrote these tests:

#### Test Class:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

  @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
  public class MainPresenterTest {

    @Mock
    private MainContract.View view;

    private MainPresenter presenter;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        presenter = new MainPresenter(view);
    }

    @Test
    public void handleScanButtonClicked() {
        presenter.handleScanButtonClicked();
        verify(view).showScanScreen();
    }

    @Test
    public void handleBackButtonClicked() {
        presenter.handleBackButtonClicked();
        verify(view).showMainScreen();
    }
}
```

#### Presenter Class:

```
public class MainPresenter implements MainContract.Presenter {

    private final MainContract.View view;

    public MainPresenter(MainContract.View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleScanButtonClicked() {
        view.showScanScreen();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleBackButtonClicked() {
        view.showMainScreen();

    }
}
```

#### MainContract Interface

```
public interface MainContract {

    /** handles UI-interaction **/

    interface Presenter {

        void handleScanButtonClicked();

        void handleBackButtonClicked();

    }

    /** handles showing/hiding UI-elements and screens **/

    interface View {

        void showScanScreen();

        void showMainScreen();

        void showWebViewScreen();
    }
}
```

#### My Testing Dependencies in build.gradle:

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19'
```

#### Test Error Message:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
view.showMainScreen();
-> at com.whatsthat.androidapp.MainPresenterTest.handleBackButtonClicked(MainPresenterTest.java:36)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Wanted but not invoked:
view.showMainScreen();
-> at com.whatsthat.androidapp.MainPresenterTest.handleBackButtonClicked(MainPresenterTest.java:36)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

    at com.whatsthat.androidapp.MainPresenterTest.handleBackButtonClicked(MainPresenterTest.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)



Wanted but not invoked:
view.showScanScreen();
-> at com.whatsthat.androidapp.MainPresenterTest.handleScanButtonClicked(MainPresenterTest.java:30)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Wanted but not invoked:
view.showScanScreen();
-> at com.whatsthat.androidapp.MainPresenterTest.handleScanButtonClicked(MainPresenterTest.java:30)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

    at com.whatsthat.androidapp.MainPresenterTest.handleScanButtonClicked(MainPresenterTest.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

#### My Project Structure

[image: project structure]

When I now run the tests without an AVD running, they will fail. I want to run those tests on my local machine only, and there should be no interactions with Android specificly, right? But to let the tests pass, I need to start an AVD, and build + deploy the APK.

Why is this, and how can I run those kind of tests properly on my local machine?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, can you post your error messages.

Comment: if `View` a concrete class or an abstraction (abstract class or interface). Sounds like the presenter is tightly coupled to a concretion that has knock on effects when exercised during tests.

Comment: @Ezio, i have added them for you.

Comment: @Nkosi MainContract.View is only an Interface, not extending another one. There is no coupling to any conrecte class in Presenter aswell. It only gets a MainContract.View interface injected in the constructor.

Comment: What happens if you try to mock the view manually? Also not seeing any annotations on the Test class

Comment: Thanks for the hint, i have added @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) to the MainPresenterTest. Now I can make the Tests pass! But there is a problem remaining, I have to rebuild manually everytime I make a change. Otherwise the Test would still fail even if i made changes that would make it pass.

Comment: @Evoxx glad to help and that you eventually got it work. That is a whole new problem which changes the scope of the original issue.

Comment: Can you also include imports of MainPresenterTest class?

Comment: @Nkosi, Yes, Thank you very much for your help! @ Mustafa: yes, i will do in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

You are not telling the framework what it should do when it encounters this line

```
view.showScanScreen()
```

and

```
view.showMainScreen()
```

do

```
doNothing().when(view).showScanScreen();
doNothing().when(view).showMainScreen();
```

You test methods will be like this

```
@Test
public void handleScanButtonClicked() {
    doNothing().when(view).showScanScreen();
    presenter.handleScanButtonClicked();
    verify(view).showScanScreen();
}

@Test
public void handleBackButtonClicked() {
    doNothing().when(view).showMainScreen();
    presenter.handleBackButtonClicked();
    verify(view).showMainScreen();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it but it did not make a difference.

Comment: did you try to debug, does the code flow goes tot he function you are calling

Comment: I digged through the method calls now, and it seems that no code inside the  Presenter.handleScanButtonClicked() method is executed. Stopping at the beginning of the handleScanButtonClicked() - Test, I reach the end of the Presenter.handleScanButtonClicked() method by pressing Step into once.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your tests on your local machine's JVM, then you need to put them in `test` package, not in `androidTest` package. `androidTest` is used for instrumentation tests and will require Android framework to run.

Check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34397524/whats-the-difference-between-src-androidtest-and-src-test-folders) for their differences.

Comment: MainPresenterTest is located in the test package. I have added an excerpt from my package location in my question.