# gradlew is not found (No such file or directory)

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I load a project from git and build it successfully on MacBook. When I type './gradlew assembleRelease' in terminal window, I get an error:

```
bash: ./gradlew: No such file or directory
```

So I check if gradlew is under the project dir, but I can not find it.
But I can still run task from 'Gradle projects' window.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

`gradlew` script is so-called Gradle wrapper, a self-contained script which allows people to run Gradle tasks without gradle installed. However it **doesn't have** to exist to execute Gradle tasks, it's absolutely optional.

You can generate Wrapper in your project by executing the task

```
gradle wrapper
```

Afterward, you can use `./gradlew` script instead of `gradle` from PATH

To specify a Gradle version use --gradle-version on the command-line.
Just execute the command:

```
gradle wrapper --gradle-version <your gradle version>
```

Take a look here for more exhaustive and comprehensive explanation: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! You solve my case. I add 'task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.0'
} ' to my build file and execute task wrapper, the gradlew script is generated under project directory again. But I still have no idea why this file was not automatically generated after the building tasks.

Comment: @huyn probably `build` task has no dependency on `wrapper` task, that makes sense: building a project should not include building a gradle wrapper, it should use a ready one

Comment: hello, i face the same problem, but when i tried 'gradle wrapper' it says **bash: gradle: command not found**, so i'm stuck again, is there anything i miss?

Comment: @MNFS
So if in your project there's no `gradlew` file  and you don't have `gradle` installed, you **must** install `gradle`. Then, if you wish, you can generate `gradle wrapper`.

Comment: @SergeyVoitovich thank you it solve caused my gradlew file is corrupt and i just copy gradlew file from another porject, but i don't know is this the best way to solve or not, i worried may be i will face another failure again because this.

Comment: @MNFS apparently it won't cause new problems, though it's certainly not the right way. The right way is to install gradle and generate your own gradlew with the version you need.

Comment: In case you don't have gradle installed on your mac, you can run `brew install gradle` and then run the command stated in this answer.

Answer (score 20):

In my case I copied gradlew file from windows(10) to linux(centos7).

So had to run

```
[user@server]$ dos2unix gradlew
```

And it worked.

Update:

If you have copied from windows as in my case. 
Do one thing, open it in notepad++, Go to View -> Show Symbol -> Show End of Line. 
You can notice `CRLF` This is the Windows EOL. Now convert it so you don't have to redo it.
To convert notepad++ -> Edit -> EOL Conversion -> Unix (`LF`)

That's it, while pushing to git fiddle aroung [.gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes)

Answer (score 14):

> bash: ./gradlew: No such file or directory

Add the execute permission for all users to the existing permissions

```
chmod +x gradlew
```

[[gradle vs gradlew]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49076817/4770877)

Comment: Well this solved my issue, I could see gradlew in directory but was not able to execute.. this gave me the hint that file might not have permission to execute.. thanks

Answer (score 3):

In my case I have  moved the project from a Windows machine to Mac and it contains carriage returns '\r'.

`brew install dos2unix`

`find . -type f -exec dos2unix {} \;`

`./gradlew clean build`

Answer (score 2):

Check the android directory if there gradlew exist or not.

If gradlew does not exist then execute following command.

On CommandLine tool, change directory to android

$ cd android

$ gradle wrapper --gradle-version 6.0.1  (you can keep your desired version)

This will generate everything related to gradle with default config.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the execute permissions.
Either use `chmod 777 gradlew` or `chmod +x gradlew`.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was missing name for data binding variable in one of the XML files.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `gradlew` file inside android folder, then run

```
- flutter clean
- flutter pub get
```

Answer (score -1):

Faced the same challenge a while back and didn't want to update my access rights to any file.

**SOLUTION:**

I navigated to the android folder within my project and run the commands from there and it worked.