# Compiling Java/gradle discord bot

Tags: java, gradle, bots, discord

I have a discord bot coded in Java and Gradle, and I need to find how to make it work.
I ask the owner of the bot and he answers me :
"./gradlew shadowJar"
What does it mean?
And what do I need to do make the bot work?

I already tried to compile the java file in jar, I tried to make a manifest but I couldn't make classes.

All I tried is:

```
javac Bot.java
```

-> Didn't work, error: package ch.qos.logback.classic does not exist

```
jar cvfm Bot.jar MANIFEST.MF server handlers commons commands audio
```

-> made a .jar file that doesn't do anything

```
jar tf Bot.jar
```

-> don't know what this does but there were no errors

```
java -jar Bot.jar
```

-> error: no main manifest attribute in bot.jar

It should make a jar file that makes the bot work but instead, it makes just errors or files that don't work.

Can someone help me to make this bot work?

Comment: He told you the exact command to run. Run it.

Comment: The `./gradlew shadowJar` is just a UNIX way of running an executable. In windows you just type `gradlew shadowJar` instead.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to understand the difference between gradle and gradlew. See below the stackoverflow link. [Difference between using gradlew and gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39627231/difference-between-using-gradlew-and-gradle). Besides, if you have the complete project along with gradle structure, go to command prompt pointing to your existing folder containing the project and run the following command.

```
gradlew clean build
```

Comment: It didn't work, error: https://pastebin.com/raw/D4BBEg3u | it says that I need a JDK installation but JDK is installed on my computer.

Comment: First check java home. Open cmd prompt and type java

Comment: I set my JAVA_HOME to the correct path (JDK installation) and I also add it in PATH but it still doesn't work, but the error is different: ```Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.``` | but I actually don't know where is the compiler output.

Comment: I found a logback.xml in the files, don't know if this can help: https://pastebin.com/raw/g7zALt8T

Comment: logback.xml file has nothing to do with compilation. Are you able to build the project using the command which I provided ?

Comment: if I type java in command prompt it says all the argument I can add with the command like java -cp

Comment: type java -version

Comment: it says: java version "1.8.0_211"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_211-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.211-b12, mixed mode)

Comment: Thats correct, go to the command prompt and point to your project directory and you can see a file like gradlew.bat and now execute the command gradlew clean build and check now.

Comment: when I execute gralew.bat it shows some green text but it also closes instantly so I can't know what it says. There is also a build.sh file but it does the same thing ( close instantly )

Comment: How did you execute, just run the command gradlew clean build in command prompt only.

Comment: It means there is some problem with the project which you downloaded or got.

Comment: download link: https://github.com/Nekos-life/neko-bot-jda | if you could make this work it would be awesome.