# Build and run gradle project on another machine

Tags: gradle

I have created a project using gradle and have created a gradle wrapper. How can I make sure that the project builds and runs on machine who don't have gradle installed?

Answer (score 0):

If you created the project using gradle (i.e. `gradle init`), then gradle should have placed a `gradlew`, or `gradlew.bat` file in the root directory of your project. Use those files to run gradle on another machine.

`gradlew` can be used on *nix machines, while `gradlew.bat` is used on windows.

In any case, gradle also creates a `gradle/wrapper` which contains the gradle jar, and this can be run on any system which has `java` installed.

See: [Difference between using gradlew and gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39627231/difference-between-using-gradlew-and-gradle)