# Downgrade Gradle version on Azure Pipeline

Tags: linux, gradle, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

After the 7.0 Gradle version my pipeline is crashing.
I want to downgrade it to 6.8.3. I tried with  `gradle wrapper --gradle-version=6.8.3` but its do nothing.
Btw its a `Microsoft-hosted agent` with `ubuntu-latest` VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find other solution, but it's work correctly.

```
- script: |
    wget https://downloads.gradle-dn.com/distributions/gradle-6.8.3-bin.zip
    unzip -d . gradle-6.8.3-bin.zip
  displayName: Download Gradle 6.8.3
- script: |
    ./../../gradle-6.8.3/bin/gradle bundleRelease
  displayName: Build Bundle
```

Comment: Glad to know it works now. Please mark your answer which will make it easier for people who have the same question to find answers.

Comment: I need to wait 48 hours to accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please add `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8.3-all.zip`  in your `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file.

For example:[image]

Here is [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/java?view=azure-devops#choose-the-version-of-gradle).

Here is my configuration of pipeline and result:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: Gradle@2
  inputs:
    gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
    tasks: 'build'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
```

[image]

Comment: I created this file to the specificatied location. Maybe the gradle is preinstalled on the ubuntu-latest image, it can be posseble? I use only `gradle bundleRelease` to build a new aab. I need to do something to use the distributionUrl as the version? Is still 7.0.

Comment: Yes, the default version of gradle is 7.0 on the ubuntu-latest image. According to [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/java?view=azure-devops#choose-the-version-of-gradle):The version of Gradle installed on the agent machine will be used unless your repository's gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file has a distributionUrl property that specifies a different Gradle version to download and use during the build. It works on my side. Can you share your configuration of pipeline?

Comment: Now it's clear what are you talking about. Now I stuck with `Error: Not found wrapperScript: gradlew`. I try to solve it.

Comment: This error message means you do not have gradlew file in your repository. You can refer to [this document](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) and [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39627231/difference-between-using-gradlew-and-gradle).

Comment: I use ionic and the android platform files is not contains the gradlew file. I built with `ionic cordova prepare android`. I tried to generate with `gradle wrapper --gradle-version 6.8.3` before use `Gradle@2` but its still 7.0.