# .\gradlew run not working when in command prompt on Windows

Tags: java, gradle

I've read for running Gradle on windows you need to execute in command prompt as `.\gradlew run` but I get a message saying
`'.\gradlew' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I have confirmed Gradle is properly installed. When I run `gradle -v` it returns version 7.6.4.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your project even use gradle**w**? (That is: the gradle wrapper, not gradle itself!)

Comment: gradlew is different from gradle, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39627231/difference-between-using-gradlew-and-gradle

Probably you get that error because you are executing .\gradlew in a directory that DOESN'T have the file "gradlew"

Comment: *When I run gradle -v it returns version 7.6.4.* Then, if you're in the right directory, you should be able to do `gradle run`

Comment: I am @Sören I am trying to follow this guide: https://blogs.oracle.com/analytics/post/create-oracle-analytics-custom-plugins-for-your-dashboard

so I assume it uses gradlew. I have set up the appropriate environment variables but when it comes time to run that graldew command, thats what I am getting.

Comment: @g00se thanks for that information. Because of that I was able to find out I needed to run ```gradle init``` . However, now I am getting 'Build failed with an exception' when i try to run ```.\gradlew run``` . Do you have any ideas on how to get around that?

It says the task 'run' not found in root project.

Comment: As explained below (and above), you don't need to run the wrapper `gradlew` as you have `gradle` itself installed. Yes, doing `gradle run` might not exist as a task. So try `gradle tasks`

Answer (score 1):

**Gradle VS gradlew theorie:**

There is a difference between gradle being installed as a native useable programm/tool and the gradlew.

gradlew is a script that is named with a suffix "w" which means "wrapper".
Using this you don't need to install gradle locally or on a server. It will download a defined version and use it afterwards which grants you more freedom between project switching OR at a neutral pipeline runner.

**Solution part**

Gradlew is a executeable script that can run on windows, mac und linux. Also on using gradle-wrapper projects a gradle.bat is provided which can be executed on windows mainly.
So please try to run `./gradlew -v` or `./graldew.bat` and you will see that it works fine.